# Use Trim Function With jsonb_array_elements in PostgreS

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, trim

```
SELECT BTRIM('"enterprise"', '"') 
> Output = enterprise
```

I need to use BTRIM function to trim the double quotes like above, with jsonb_array_elements function.

I have a query like below,

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(json_column->'Fields')->'field_name' as "column"
FROM table_a
```

Which returns

```
column
"Value1"
"Value2"
"Value3"
```

I need the output without double quotes like below.

```
column
Value1
Value2
Value3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trim function is not required, just use [`->>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html) to get JSON array elements as text :

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(json_column->'Fields')->>'field_name' as "column"
FROM table_a
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  that you  can use the `BTRIM` function to remove the " to the output of `jsonb_array_elements` casted to text:

```sql
SELECT BTRIM ((jsonb_array_elements(json_column->'Fields')->'field_name')::text,'"') as "column"
FROM table_a
```

Comment: Just use the correct operator ->>